# Ajax.BeginForm is rendering with differently in HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RespondToFollowRequest", ajaxOptions))
{
<input type="hidden" name="followerID" value="@Model.MemberIdSentFrom" />
<div>
     <input class="Acceptbutton" type="submit" value="Accept" 
     name="btnAccept" id="btnAccept" />
</div>
}
```

its HTML Rendering is

```
<input type="hidden" value="68aad827-3993-4a21-9846-731486409b1a" name="followerID">
<div>
<input id="btnAccept" class="Acceptbutton" type="submit" name="btnAccept" value="Accept">
</div>
```

While I have another button in the same Partial view and that is rendering as:

```
<form id="form1" method="post" data-ajax-update="#tblNotification" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax="true" action="/Notification/RespondToFollowRequest">
<input type="hidden" value="68aad827-3993-4a21-9846-731486409b1a" name="followerID">
<div>
<input id="btnReject" class="Rejectbutton" type="submit" name="btnReject" value="Reject">
</div>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me finding why this is happening?

Comment: How does the razor code look like for the *second* button? And are the same `ajaxOptions` used for both forms?